# No puedo ver un archivo txt que abri en Python

Tags: python

Acabo de empezar a usar Python, y ya tengo problemas para abrir un archivo txt.
No me tira error al abrirlo (supuestamente) pero cuando quiero que me lo muestre no lo hace. Estoy escribiendo bien el codigo?

Gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenida Magali a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Sube el código directamente, en vez de una imagen y sera mas fácil ayudarte con el problema.

Comment: Hola Magali, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. Debes colocar el código como texto, no usar una imagen ya que dificulta la lectura y la reproducción del mismo. En cuanto a tu problema, lo primero es que **nunca llamas a tu función `main`**,  (`main()`), por lo que no ejecutas nada, solo defines una función. Tienes más cosas, abres en modo escritura y no en modo lectura, no lees el contenido del archivo en ningún momento (`file.read()`), usas `"\"` en vez de `"/"` para la ruta, etc

Comment: Yo tuve muchos problemas para poder leer un archivo .txt Mi solución fue crearlo, guardar la información, luego leerlo en django. Se acabó el problema. Pero me costó todo un dia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes algunos problemas en tu código, (además que no parecieras estar invocándolo en ningún momento) veamos:

1. `file` es un objeto que representa el archivo abierto ([`fileobj`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object)), pero NO es el contenido del mismo, para poder obtener el contenido deberías leer desde dicho objeto, por ejemplo `file.read()`.
2. Estas abriendo el archivo en modo escritura, `w`, lo cual hace que en primer lugar se trunque, por consiguiente no habrá contenido para leer. Para leer es necesario abrir en modo lectura: `r`.
3. Si usas las barras habituales `\`, deberías escaparlas con `\\` o mucho mejor como te comentó FJSevilla es usar la contra barra `/` que es consistente en cualquier sistema operativo.
4. No olvides que de la forma que estás abriendo el archivo, es buena práctica cerrarlo luego de usarlo con `file.close()`.

Resumiendo, tu código podría ser el siguiente:

```
file = open("c:/carpeta/tu_archivo.txt", "r")
print(file.read())
file.close()
```

Por último, mucho más elegante y seguro es usar los [manejadores de contexto](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=open#io.IOBase) para el abrir y cerrar automáticamente un archivo cuando se lo deja de usar (se sale del bloque):

```
with open("c:/carpeta/tu_archivo.txt", "r"):
    print(file.read())
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!! Después de 4 horas pude abrir el archivo! :)